# How to trigger Cloud Functions from Google cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How to send the `DocumentReference.getId()` that is generated every time a new document was added to firestore from Android Studio to cloud function that triggers when there is a write/create operation on Firestore.
I tried following

```
'use strict';
const  https = require( 'firebase-functions');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.helloUser = functions.firestore
    .document('BankInform/Moj2HBrxepX5R7FonvrO')
    .onUpdate(event =>{
    var newValue = event.data.data();
return event.data.ref.update({
    "status": "Success"
    });

    });
```

But I have to give the autoid of document.How to pass document id from android studio to cloud functions

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, I recommend starting with the [documentation on Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). If you got/get stuck, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use wildcards in your function:

```
exports.helloUser = functions.firestore
    .document('BankInform/{transactionId}')
    .onUpdate(event =>{
        var transactionId = event.params.transactionId
        console.log(transactionId);  // Moj2HBrxepX5R7FonvrO
    });
```

As you can see, you should be able to use `event.params` to get the appropriate document name from the function.